# format string is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to string.format

Tags: java, android, localization, xliff

Using Java in Android Studio, I wrote this in xml to translate the string "Name" into other language and keep the string "anything" as it is

```xml
<string name="order_summary_name">Name: <xliff:g id="name" example="Aya">$s</xliff:g></string>
```

**MainActivity**

```
getString(R.string.order_summary_name,"anything")
```

this error occurred "format string is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to string.format"

if i used only

```
 getString(getString(R.string.order_summary_name) )
```

the output will be : Name : $s

i want the output in english to be Name: anything

and in other language : Translated Word : anything

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to do with the `xliff` tag but the following mau help you

```xml
<string name="order_summary_name">Name: $s</string>
```

```java
getString(R.string.order_summary_name,"anything")
```

Output

> Name: anything

Comment: i want to translate the string Name into other language and keep anything as it is / so when i use that language in my phone the string Name will be translated while anything will not

Comment: OK. My answer suits your case. You just have to repeat the strings.xml file in the language res dir you want

Comment: when i have to use xliff tag?